# Unexpected behavior with nginx rewrite to location alias

Tags: nginx, browserstack

For some reason, the rewrite to `location /ancient/` isn't working.

If I switch out "/ancient/" for "http://google.com" (or any URL), the rewrite works. So I know my check for IE 6 is working.

Also, if I try to directly access `/etc/static/ancient/` directly from the browser, I can. So I know the desired files are accessible.

```
location / {

    if ($http_user_agent ~ "MSIE 6.0") {
        rewrite ^ /ancient/;
        break;
    }
}

location /ancient/ {
    alias /Users/myusernametho/sterling/etc/static/ancient/;
}
```

I've run this on BrowserStack and with curl (UA spoofing) with the same results.

Am I misunderstanding something about how the rewrite directive works?

Answer (score 0):

There is a need for the optional [flag parameter](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html)(`break`, `last`, `redirect`) in your rewrite. in your case.
You forgot to write the `break` at the end of your `rewrite` directive like so:

```
rewrite ^ /ancient/ break;
```

and you don't need the `break` at the end of the `if`